# What does "WSREP Aborter Idle" mean in a MariaDB Galera cluster?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-cluster

I've tried to Google *WSREP Aborter Idle* but there are literally 3 results. Does anyone know what this means?

[image]

Should I be concerned that the these processes have been opened for so long or is this just part of the normal cluster operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extensive searching the only reference I can find is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/codership-mysql/+bug/498798) filed with Codership. Within that report the following quote makes reference to the process and seems to point to this being both required and part of the normal operation of the Galera cluster.

> wsrep aborter thread is missing in the process list in node carthusian. Checking by gdb, shows that aborter thread is alive and working well.
>   Also whole cluster is healthy and works good under sqlgen test load

If anyone has further details about this I'd be interested to learn more!